# Pin ASP.Net 5.0 version to 'beta4' in Dockerfile

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core

Before the release of ASP.NET 5.0 beta 5, I had a working beta 4 application running in a Docker container with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta4

# Install NPM
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# Install bower and grunt
RUN npm install -g bower
RUN npm install -g grunt-bower-cli
RUN npm install -g grunt
RUN npm install -g grunt-cli
RUN npm install -g grunt-bower-task

# Install Git (for bower)
RUN apt-get -y install git

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dnu", "restore"]

WORKDIR ./src/myapp

RUN ["npm", "install"]
RUN ["bower", "install", "--allow-root"]
RUN ["grunt", "bower_concat"]
RUN ["grunt", "prod"]

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT sleep 99999999 | dnx . kestrel
```

However, upon running it now (since the release of beta 5), I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.IApplicationEnvironment' has been registered.
```

I believe this is the same problem as https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/588 but I don't know how to 'pin' the version to beta 4 in this setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with `project.json` rather than the Dockerfile:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
    ...
}
```

Changed to the following made it work again:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta4",
    ...
}
```